# WPF datagrid multiple row selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a customcontrol similar to wpf datagrid. I need to select the multiple rows and get the column values of all the selected rows. Could anyone help to solve this.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your custom control? code may be.

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more information for the question, but you could look at LINQ?
Maybe you can work with this:

```
    List<int> rows = new List<int>{1,2,3};

    var values = from row in datagrid
                 where rows.Contains(row.Select(e => e.rowindex))
                 select new { Value = row.value };
```